# Create a counter in a shell script that will increase every time when a file from the current director have more than 8 lines?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, files, directory

How can I create a counter in a shell script that will increase every time when a file from the current director have more than 8 lines and after how can I generate two lists, one of this with the files that have more than 8 lines and the other with files that have less than 8 lines?
I tried this, but I'm sure that is incorrect.

```
contor=0 
while [ contor -le 100 ] 
do 
      echo $contor 
      contor=expr $contor + 1 
done
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange. What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include any additional information.

Answer (score 5):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob

long_files=()
short_files=()

for name in ./*; do
        [[ ! -f $name ]] && continue

        numlines=$( wc -l <"$name" )

        if [[ numlines -gt 8 ]]; then
                long_files+=( "$name" )
        elif [[ numlines -lt 8 ]]; then
                short_files+=( "$name" )
        fi
done

printf 'There are %d files with more than 8 lines:\n' "${#long_files[@]}"
printf '\t%s\n' "${long_files[@]}"

printf 'There are %d files with less than 8 lines:\n' "${#short_files[@]}"
printf '\t%s\n' "${short_files[@]}"
```

This would do literally what you asked for, by iterating over all names in the current directory and dividing the names up into two lists (arrays), `long_files` and `short_files`, depending on whether the files have more or less than eight lines.  Files with exactly eight lines are not stored in a list.  Names corresponding to non-regular files (i.e. directories etc.) are skipped with the `-f` test and the `continue` statement.

The number of lines is calculated using `wc -l`, so there's no need to use a counter to count individual lines in files.

The script sets the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options, enabling us to correctly deal with totally empty directories and with hidden files.

At the end, the two lists are outputted.

Test run:

```
$ bash script.sh
There are 1 files with more than 8 lines:
        ./script.sh
There are 3 files with less than 8 lines:
        ./.bash_profile
        ./.bashrc
        ./.zshrc
```

---

To create two files with the lists in them, either print the lists to the files at the end of the above script with

```
printf '%s\n' "${long_files[@]}"  >long_files.list
printf '%s\n' "${short_files[@]}" >short_files.list
```

or print to the files in the main loop of the program, instead of adding the names to the arrays:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob

rm -f long_files.list short_files.list

for name in ./*; do
        [[ ! -f $name ]] && continue

        numlines=$( wc -l <"$name" )

        if [[ numlines -gt 8 ]]; then
                printf '%s\n' "$name" >>long_files.list
        elif [[ numlines -lt 8 ]]; then
                printf '%s\n' "$name" >>short_files.list
        fi
done
```

To *count* the number of files longer than eight lines, use a counter variable that you increment when a long file is detected, or if using arrays of long and short files, get the number of long files with `"${#long_files[@]}"` after the loop (as I've shown in the first piece of code).